# Optimize list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to optimize the following code which is now taking around 15-20 minutes to execute.

I want to get the index of words in `inverse_vocab` list which are also present in `subsampled_words`.

```
sub_sample_vocab_id = [idx for idx, word in tqdm.tqdm(enumerate(inverse_vocab)) if (word in subsampled_words)]
```

where `sub_sample_words` is a list of words with size `511617`
and `inverse_vocab` is another list of words with size `77292`.

For example:

```
sub_sample_words = ['mathew','alt','atheism','faq','atheist','resources','summary','books']

inverse_vocab = ['atheism','address', 'also','faq','atheist']

sub_sample_vocab_id = [0,3,4]
```

since `atheism, faq, atheist` are the words in `inverse_vocab` that are also present in `sub_sample_words` and the final result in `sub_sample_vocab_id` is the id of those words.

Comment: Make ``sub_sample_words`` a set instead of a list.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thanks that might help alot

Comment: Just as heads up that you might have more luck on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: To be clear you want the index of words from `inverse_vocab` if they appear in `sub_sample_words` right?

Comment: @JonSG yes right

Comment: @JonSG, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Comment: @TobySpeight I agree that more work needs to be done to bring this question up to acceptable standards. Note, I did not provide an answer and prompted the use to further clarify their issue. I just pointed out that questions of the type "*my code works, help me make it faster*" are more aligned philosophically with CodeReview. Do you disagree? I'm not sure I should be expected to point out the required etiquette on other sites. It is the responsibility of the user to understand how they should participate. If this is some sort of "Meta" driven requirement I will certainly abide by it though.